# Perl non-greedy regex matching more than it should

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I have the following text from which I need to remove some `wdiff` output.

```
text='Иса Мәсіхтің елшісі Петірден [-(-] осы күнәкар дүниеде [-)-] жат жерлік болып, Понти, Ғалатия, [-Қападоқия, Азия және Бітүния аймақтарында шашыраған [ сенушілерге дұғай сәлем ].-] {+Қападоқия… https://t.co/.......... [Петірдің 1 1:1-5]+}'
```

I'm trying to remove a `[- -]` block of text with the non-greedy perl regex `\[-.*?-\]`, but it is matching the previous blocks too:

```
$ perl -pe 's|\[-.*?-\] {\+(\S+… https://t.co/.*)\+}|\1|' <<<"$text"
Иса Мәсіхтің елшісі Петірден Қападоқия… https://t.co/.......... [Петірдің 1 1:1-5]
```

Expected output:

```
$ perl -pe 's|\[-.*?-\] {\+(\S+… https://t.co/.*)\+}|\1|' <<<"$text"
Иса Мәсіхтің елшісі Петірден [-(-] осы күнәкар дүниеде [-)-] жат жерлік болып, Понти, Ғалатия, Қападоқия… https://t.co/.......... [Петірдің 1 1:1-5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve simplified your input string to `qABxBCzABxBCDEFw`, where

```
A represents [
B represents -
C represents ]
D represents {\+
E represents the text between the +s (including the URL)
F represents \+}
Lower case letters represent everything else.
```

So here are some substitute commands run against the input:

```
                                  Command                          Output
0. Input text:                                                     qABxBCzABxBCDEFw
1. Non-greedy:                   's|AB.*?BCD(E)F|\1|'              qEw
2. Greedy:                       's|AB.*BCD(E)F|\1|'               qEw
3. Restricted Non-greedy:        's|AB[^B]*?BCD(E)F|\1|'           qABxBCzEw
4. Restricted Greedy:            's|AB[^B]*BCD(E)F|\1|'            qABxBCzEw
5. Constrained Non-greedy:       's|(.*)AB.*?BCD(E)F|\1\2|'        qABxBCzEw
6. Constrained Greedy:           's|(.*)AB.*BCD(E)F|\1\2|'         qABxBCzEw
```

Command 1 is the one you tried. 
Command 2 is the same thing, but not non-greedy. 
As you’re aware, they produce the same result.

It seems to me that non-greedy applies only to the *length* of the text matched
by something like `.*`.  ***It doesn’t affect the starting point.*** 
Regex matches always begin as soon as they can. 
So, when you say `AB.*?BC` (i.e., `\[-.*?-\]`),
it’s matching the *first* `[-` on the line. 
Then, you expect, it’s matching the shortest possible string
of any characters ending with `-]`. 
You might expect that this would be `[-(-]`. 
But look closer: the regex is `AB.*?BCD(E)F`,
so it must match the shortest possible string
of any characters ending with `-] {+`. 
This forces it to consume everything up almost to the URL.

I have written four alternative commands that seem to do what you want. 
The “Restricted” ones (3 and 4) search, not for `AB.*BC`,
but for `AB[^B]*BC`; in words, `AB`…`BC` with no `B`s in the “…”. 
In your case, that means `[-`…`-]` with no `-`s in the “…”. 
The “Constrained” ones (5 and 6) force the `AB.*BC` match to start
as late as possible by putting a greedy `.*` in front of them. 
It turns out not to matter whether you do the `AB.*BC` part
as greedy or non-greedy in these, either.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a [negative lookaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word):

```
perl -pe 's|\[-((?!-\]).)*-\] {\+(\S+… https://t.co/.*)\+}|\2|' <<<$text
```

The problem is the first occurence of `[-` matches. Then the non-greediness of the pattern doesn't take the desired effect, it doesn't matter how non-greedy it is. With a negative lookaround you can match everthing except of the string `-]`, then it matches only the occurence before the `{+...+}` part.